# How to put a spinner in the center of a bootstrap 3 div col-md-x?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, spinner

I want to put a spinner inside a div that contains a video.

This video takes a few seconds to display as it is hosted on aws.

I have managed to make the spinner but it takes up the whole page. I can't get it to adapt to the div it is entered in.

```css
#cover-div-spin {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:2;
    /*display:none;*/
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

#cover-div-spin::after {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #c4040c;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:48%;top:40%;
    -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
    animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4" style="background:orange;">
  <span><b>Example</b></span>
  <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <div id="cover-div-spin"></div>
     <video class="embed-responsive-item" src="" controls muted></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JorgePalaciosZaratiegui/pdzm1ano/17/

Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `#cover-div-spin` should have an `absolute position` instead of a `fixed` one.

To understand more about positionning, let's read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

#### position: absolute

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. **It is positioned relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor**, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block.

#### position: fixed

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. **It is positioned relative
> to the initial containing block established by the viewport**

I've also changed hte `#cover-div-spin` `display:flex;`, it will allow us to easily center the spinner.

```css
#cover-div-spin {
    position:absolute; /* absolute instead of fixed */
    width:100%;
    left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:2;
    display: flex;  /* Allow us to easily center the spinner */
    align-items: center; /* Vertical alignement */
    justify-content: center; /* Horizontal alignement */
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

#cover-div-spin::after {
    /* Removed all position rules */
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #c4040c;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
    animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-4" style="background:orange;">
  <span><b>Example</b></span>
  <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
     <div id="cover-div-spin"></div>
     <video class="embed-responsive-item" src="" controls muted></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

to be exact center, the `left` and `top` cannot be full `50%`, but, 50% - half the width of the spinner (on your case the spinner is 100px, so half is 50px), like this (i just change the left & top, and remove duplicate left and top at the bottom)

```
#cover-div-spin::after {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    top: calc(50% - 50px);
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #c4040c;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    /* left:48%; top:40%; remove this */
    -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
    animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
}
```

and if you want to make the spinner only on the div, just change the position on `#cover-div-spin` to absolute, like this

```
#cover-div-spin {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#cover-div-spin::after {
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

you have to just add this 3 line in #cover-div-spin::after otherwise all code lines are perfect.

when we move any element 50% top and left we have to minus the element -50% which ever the side we use.

if we want to align vertically center then it will be like top:50%; trasnfrom:translateY(-50%); and if we need to center horizontally then left:50%; trasnfrom:translateX(-50%); and if we need to center both horizontal and vertical then you can use above code;

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following example could help.

```css
.col-md-4,
.embed-responsive {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.col-md-4 span {
  height: 100%;
}
.col-md-4 {
  height: 12rem;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
#cover-div-spin {
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  position: absolute;
}
#cover-div-spin::after {
  border: 1rem solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 1rem solid #c4040c;
  width: 6rem;
  height: 6rem;
  align-self: center;
  content: '';
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
  animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
}
.embed-responsive-item {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4" style="background:orange;">
  <span><b>Example</b></span>
  <div id="cover-div-spin"></div>
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">   
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" src="" controls muted></video>
  </div>
</div>
```